# Flutter: Why is content replacing values in List instead of being added to List?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a grid of 26 buttons and each button represents a letter of the alphabet.
When a user taps a button I want the associated letter to be added to a `List` called `selectedLetters`.

So if a user selects buttons A, D, and F, `selectedLetters` should look like `[A, D, F]`.

The issue with my code is that when I select a letter it replaces the current letter in the list, instead of adding it to the end of the list.

How can I change my code so that letters are added to the list instead of being added to the list and replacing the current letter?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AlphabetButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final String letter;

  AlphabetButton({this.letter});

  @override
  _AlphabetButtonState createState() => _AlphabetButtonState();
}

class _AlphabetButtonState extends State<AlphabetButton> {

  bool buttonToggle = false;

  List<String> selectedLetters = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
        color: buttonToggle ? Colors.green : Colors.orange,
        child: Center(
          child: Text('${widget.letter}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() => buttonToggle = !buttonToggle);
          _addLetterToList('${widget.letter}');
          print(selectedLetters);
          },
    );
  }

  //Add selected letter to list of letters
  void _addLetterToList(addedLetter) {

    if (selectedLetters.contains(addedLetter)) {
      selectedLetters.remove(addedLetter);
    } else {
      selectedLetters.add(addedLetter);
    }

  }

}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: where you are using this widget/class ?

Comment: Have you checked what `'${widget.letter}'` contains when clicking a button?

Comment: @NaveenAvidi I'm using it in the build widget of another stateful widget

Comment: You should save the selected letter inside the parent class !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selectedLetters` array shouldn't be in this `stateful widget` class, because as per my knowledge you are calling this stateful widget to build single alphabet button widget means you are creating 26 selectedLetters arrays. 
So what you have to do is that you initialize the array in parent stateful widget where you are calling this `AlphabetButton` widget and add a callback to the button click such that every selected letter will be added instead of overriding.

Answer (score 1):

```
  List<String> alphabets =['A','B','C','D','E','F',
                          'G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
                          'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'],
  selection=[];

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
    padding:EdgeInsets.all(15),
      color:Colors.white,
     alignment:Alignment.center,
      child:GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate:SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount:7,
         mainAxisSpacing: 5, crossAxisSpacing: 5,
        ),
      itemCount:alphabets.length,
       itemBuilder:(con,ind){
         return InkWell(
           onTap:(){
             setState((){
               if(selection.contains(alphabets[ind]))
                 selection.remove(alphabets[ind]);
               else
               selection.add(alphabets[ind]);
             });
           },
           child: Container(
           padding:EdgeInsets.all(10),
             alignment:Alignment.center,
           decoration:BoxDecoration(
           color:selection.contains(alphabets[ind])?Colors.blueAccent:Colors.grey,
           borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(7)
           ),
             child:Text(alphabets[ind],
                       style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black))
           ),
         );
       }
      )
    );
  }
```

[image: Scr]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have multiple AlphabetButton. Now from your code every AlphabetButton has its own List of selected letters. You can pass every button the same List and then they won't replace anything